# Python: Function is not appending to list in intended chronological order

Tags: python, list, function

I have function 1 `ma_generate` which generates a list of numbers called `ma_list`, with one of the inputs being `period`.

I have function 2 `multi_gen` which iterates function 1 four times, each time with a different value of `time`. Each time function 1 is iterated, a list `list1` (or `list2`, `list3`, `list4` depending on which iteration) is set to equal the produced `ma_list`. So the intended output is to have 4 different lists (`list1`, `list2`, `list3`, `list4`) which are different versions of `ma_list`, with the period input changing each of the 4 times.

Here is the code:

```
def ma_generate(dataset, method, period): ##Function 1
    ma_list.clear()
    if method == "sma":
        for i in range(0,period-1):
            ma_list.append(0)
        for i in range(period-1,len(dataset)):
            ma = np.mean(dataset[i+1-period:i+1])
            ma_list.append(ma)
    return 

def multi_gen(dataset, method, p1, p2, p3, p4):
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p1)
    list1.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p2)
    list2.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p3)
    list3.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p4)
    list4.append(ma_list)
    return
```

However, all 4 of the generated lists are the same. They are all what "list4" should be. (the ma_list output of ma_generate when period = p4). Why are they the same?

Comment: ``ma_list`` is always the same object that you keep mutating. So no matter what's the content at a given point, unless you assign a **copy** to your lists, they will keep referencing the same object and in the end will all contain the final mutation of it. You should read up on mutable and immutable objects.

Comment: Short fix: Change `ma_list.clear()` to `nonlocal ma_list` followed by `ma_list = []`. Or change each `list#.append(ma_list)` to `list#.append(ma_list[:])`. Or the *slightly* more invasive option, just change `ma_list.clear()` to `ma_list = []` and *return* the brand new `ma_list` (which is the Pythonic solution; operating on shared globals this way is code smell); you'd use the return value as the thing to `append`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks that does indeed work. I used your second option. Does that one work because it references the contents of ma_list, as opposed to the object itself?

Comment: @Simplex1: Yes, it's (shallow) copying the contents of `ma_list` and passing that copy to `append`. If the items stored in `ma_list` are themselves mutable objects that get reused, necessitating a deep copy, you're change it to `list#.append(copy.deepcopy(ma_list))` (adding an `import copy` to the top of your file).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your objective well but from what I see here, all the lists are getting the same version of the ma_list, making it impossible for the lists to be different from each other.

```
ma_generate(dataset, method, p1)
    list1.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p2)
    list2.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p3)
    list3.append(ma_list)
    ma_generate(dataset, method, p4)
    list4.append(ma_list)
```

Comment: But ma_generate is supposed to generate a new version of ma_list each time since the input of the grand function is different. It does do this when I run each section individually. BTW you wrote ma_generate as the main function, it is "multi_gen".